# Can't access any values on my forms

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have a C# Winforms Application and I'm using the main form to control the other this way:

```
public Rel_Entitys RelForm1;
public Struct_Inc StructForm1;
public DataLoad DataLoadForm1;
public Asset_Inc AssetForm1;
public Estimates_Inc EstimatesForm1;
public Options OptionsForm1;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RelForm1 = new Rel_Entitys();
    StructForm1 = new Struct_Inc();
    DataLoadForm1 = new DataLoad();
    AssetForm1 = new Asset_Inc();
    OptionsForm1 = new Options();
    EstimatesForm1 = new Estimates_Inc();
}
```

And then I access them this way:

```
private void barButtonItem6_ItemClick(
                object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    StructForm1.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

Is working fine for me to load data from database to this forms but when I try to get any value from any field they are null/empty. I already tried to use `this.StructForm1.txt1.Text` but nothing returns. What am I doing wrong? I use this form declaration to become more easy handle the form and call your methods but I not sure that is the right way to do it.

[Update]

I'm starting to think that is something related to my methods. If a set a value for the field on form_load and then get it from the method

```
public void SaveEstimate() {...}
```

It is empty again. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try applying it to anything? Or is that literally the line of code you used?

Comment: Do you try to retrieve a value after the form closed?

Comment: Please show the code where you try to get a value of a field.

Comment: Did you change the modifier property on the `txt1` control, in c# the default is private.

Comment: This is my exact code. I'm using a opened form, that's for sure. I'm trying to get values the simple way > "public void Save()
                var est = new Structure { 
                    stc_Business = cbx_Bussines.SelectedText, 
                    stc_Company = cbx_Company.Text, 
                };"

Comment: I have tried to set the modifier to Public and to use capsule "Public string Txt() { get { return txt1.text; }" but no sucess at all.

Comment: Try to set value before you get it like: txt1.Text = "ABC"; var newValue = txt1.Text;

Comment: Habibillah I tried your suggestion and it works. If a set the value and then get it is everything okay. No errors and the value is correct. What it means? Cause I still can't access the values that I  inputted on form.

Comment: I notice you're using DevEx controls. What is the type of `txt1`? If it's `DevExpress.XtraEditors.TextEdit` see what the value of the `EditValue` property is.

Comment: You are right Stainy I use DevEx controls but to set values I use txt1.text. Also my problem is to get values from any control like: comboeditors, listviews and textedits.

Comment: If you have an answer to the question you should post it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are creating multiple instances of forms. Just a quick check. Make the fields static and then see if these are still Null(empty).

```
public static Rel_Entitys RelForm1;
public static Struct_Inc StructForm1;
public static DataLoad DataLoadForm1;
public static Asset_Inc AssetForm1;
public static Estimates_Inc EstimatesForm1;
public static Options OptionsForm1;
```

Comment: @TulioVS then double check if form_load is even called. put a break point :-)

Comment: Same as before. The instance is happening on form_load normally.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the textbox you call `txt1` is Public.

Select your textbox, go to the properties window, find Modifiers and set it to Public.

Comment: Even when Modifiers is Public the values are null.